# Sporadic long query execution in Oracle RDS

Tags: oracle, rds

We are experiencing sporadic long queries execution in our application. The database is Oracle 12.1 RDS. I can see in AppDynamics that query was executed for 13s, I'm executing it myself in Oracle SQL Developer and it never takes longer than 0.1s. I can't put query here as there are 3 of them that sporadically give execution time longer than 10s and for each of them I can't reproduce it in SQL Developer.
We've started to log Execution plan for long running queries using /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ and it is the same as if query executed for 0.1s except the fact that it doesn't have such a record "1 SQL Plan Directive used for this statement".

I'm looking for any ideas that could help to identify the root cause of this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you've got a cached execution plan which works fine for most parameter values, or combination of parameter values, but which fails badly for certain values/combinations. You can try adding a non-filtering predicate such as `1 = 1` to your WHERE clause. [I've read](https://oracle-randolf.blogspot.com/2009/02/how-to-force-hard-parse.html) but haven't tested that this can be used to force a hard parse, but it may be that you need to change the value (e.g. `1 = 1`, `2 = 2`, `3 = 3`, etc) for each execution of your query.